# Reverse Engineering an Installer

Tags: installation, windows-installer, reverse-engineering

Has anyone got any experience in doing this?

Specifically, I'd like to find out if any registry keys are being written and what files are going where when I run an MSI.

I was thinking of using [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see what the msiexec process is doing while I run through it but just thought I'd run it by here to see if anyone has a better method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bit rusty, but here's a few (maybe) helpful pointers.

There is a tool called [Orca](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255905) that you can use to edit MSI files.

There was also [Wise for Windows](http://www.wise.com/Products/Installations/WiseInstallationStudio.aspx), which is now called something else, and I'm not sure what you'll be able to do with the trial, it definitely had the ability to edit MSI files.

I was going to suggest FileMon and RegMon on their own, but I just saw they've actually been merged into ProcMon, shows how behind the times I am :)

Comment: Orca looks very interesting. Can't believe I've never heard of it before. I'll have a play around with it.

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of the whole point behind Windows Installer.  Make it declarative not imperative so systems administrators can see what the heck it's doing and if needed tweak it to bend to their will.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally,  the setup author used only the  Registry and COM tables so it's very easy to just look with Orca what's being done.   However many setup authors produce less then idea installs.  In those cases I use InstallWatch to snapshot the registry before and after to generate a difference.

[InstallWatch Pro](http://www.brothersoft.com/downloads/installwatch-pro-2.5c.html)

You'll see other line noise from processes running on the machine but you learn to filter those with experience.  ( E.g. the install didn't change the crypto seed or the MRU's and ShellBags )

Comment: For files should be able to say msiexec /a foo.msi TARGETDIR=C:\EXTRACT\  but again if they are using out of process custom actions it won't be expressed.   There are other tools such as InControl and InstallShield Repackager that will capture this stuff.   We usually think of using these tools for capturing what a legacy / pre-MSI install is doing as a good MSI should be declarative.